# How to create a style object to bind with React component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Here I created a sample example. As you can see I add **applyColor** Style object to apply styles.

```
import React from 'react'


const applyColor = {
  color: 'red'
}

export const App = () => {
    const renderData = () => {
        return (
        <>
        <section style={applyColor}>
            <p>Paragraph</p>
            <div>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <span>Span</span>
            </div>
        </section>
        </>
        )
    }
   
    return <>
        {renderData()}
    </>
}
```

How can I modify applyColor Object to access the child from parent element `<section />`?

And I dont want to use any third party like **styled-components** and **material-ui/styles**.
Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

In short, no way unless you do it directly to the child.

```
  <div style={{ color: red }} />
```

That's what the `style` is made for. However, everything is coded as Javascript code, so you can do it manually via `props`.

```
  return <Child color="red" />

  const Child = ({ color }) => {
    return <div style={{ color }} />
  }
```

Every big UI system has their unique way of handling this, ex. Material and etc.

But trusted me, unless you are making small css changes, `styled-components` like Css-in-Js approach isn't avoidable. Because passing the flag from Parent to Child is just too much work to manage by your own, not difficult but tedious. This is just my two cents.

Or you can use a traditional CSS approach, just put everything through CSS class. This way you can just include one copy of css. But the problem of that approach is that you can't pass a flag into the CSS so in the end you come back to the same boat above :)